# Aplication of Ramsey theory in group theory

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, ramsey-theory

Let $G$ be a infinite group. How to show that there is a $A\subseteq G$ infite such that 
$$\forall x,y,z\in A\;\; \big(xy=z\Leftrightarrow (x=y=z=x^2)\big)$$

---

I've tried to define the coloring $c:[G]^3\to \{0,1\}$ by
$$
c(\{x,y,z\})=
\begin{cases}
0&,\text{ if } (xy=z)\Rightarrow(x=y=z=x^2); \text{ or}\\
1&, \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
By Ramsey theorem, there is an infinite set $A\subseteq G$ such that $c\restriction [A]^3$ is constant. As I'm working in $[A]^3$, the negation of $x=y=z=x^2$ becomes $z\neq x^2$; but, assuming that, I was not able to reach a contradiction.

Comment: There is something wrong here because $x=x^2 \Leftrightarrow x=1$.

Comment: Is this suppose to be: for $x,y,z \in A$, $xy=z$ if and only if $x=y$ and  $z=x^2$?

Comment: @PaulPlummer, in the homework sheet is $(x=y=z=x^2)$. I've send an e-mail for the professor, but he did not answer until the present time.